# Odoo - Colspan and col-border making records invisible

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I asked a question how to show borders in table [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45444767/odoo-view-customization-with-colspan-or-may-be-col) which was answered and it working perfectly like below

[image]

But once i click on the record of grid to edit something and finish editing all the fields which have `col-border` or `col-span` attribute are hidden like below

[image]

Comment: After doing a lot research on the code written by @Viki Chavada. I came to point that when ever i add subheading on any field this happens and if i remove that i start working again

Comment: but i am unable to fix that issue in subheading

Comment: I just tried it by editing and it's working perfectly and not hiding any thing.